# jQuery Ajax Post with data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Am trying to call a PHP file when onclick of a button occurs with some parameters. It is getting executed till alert statement in jsfile.js. After that the ajax part is not getting executed.. Help me out..

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="jsfile.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <button onclick="cart(0)"> hi </button>
            <p id="disp"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**jsfile.js**

```
function cart(id1) {
    var id = id1;
    alert("enterd " + id);
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "hi";
    $.ajax({
        url: "/add.php ",
        type: "POST",    
        data: {
            item_id: id,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            // document.getElementById("total_items").value = response;
            document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = response;
        },
        error: function() {
            alert("error");
        }    
    });    
}
```

**add.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['item_id']) && !empty($_POST['item_id'])) {
    // if(count($_POST)>0)
        echo "success";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: If you put an `alert` in your `success` callback, does that show?

Comment: I forgot to include ajax script at beginning of the html document.. But even after that the success part is not getting executed..  Only the error part is getting getting executed..

Comment: From JQuery docs: "__type__ (default: 'GET') ... An alias for method."

Comment: `url:"/add.php ",` Is the __add.php__ file located in the web root directory?

Answer (score 6):

In your `jsfile.js` file, please correct the following points which I have mentioned as comments on the following code.

```
function cart(id1) {
    var id = id1;
    alert("enterd " + id);
    document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = "hi";
    $.ajax({
        url: "/add.php ",
        method: "POST", // First change type to method here    
        data: {
            item_id: id,
        },
        success: function(response) {
            document.getElementById("disp").innerHTML = response;
        },
        error: function(error) {
            alert("error" + error);
        }
    });    
}
```

Comment: Why quote `id`? It's not a string, it's a variable, instantiated at the top of the cart function: `var id=id1;`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

Change it and try

```
 type:"POST" ->  method: "POST"
```

If your jquery version is >= 1.5 use it this way.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "add.php",
  method: "POST",
  data: { item_id: id},
}).done(function(response) {
  ......
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
  ......
});
```

Load Jquery Before your JS file.

Comment: Even if i change to method from type only the error part is getting executed.. Is it mandatory to include done and fail instead of success and error..?

Comment: what do you get in error response? check using developer tool

Comment: either your url path is not matching or either some other response from server is executing the error function.