# I need fix some buttons that do not change the content according to the chosen category of buttons

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with this code, I have several buttons with various categories and when you click it it should change what it shows according to the category you have chosen, as I have it now it does not change what it shows, I hope you can help me fellows.

Here is a link of a video that shows the problem:
https://www.loom.com/share/1371ed7d195544269e28197cafd25407

```
<?php

?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php get_template_part('template_parts/banner-casos-de-exito') ?>

<section class="section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="section__body mt-0">
            <div class="grid-history">

                <div class="row">
                    <?php

                        $terms = get_terms('historias-de-exitos');
                        $count = count($terms);

                        if ( $count > 0 )
                        {

                    ?>

                            <ul id="filters-2" class="clearfix">
                                <li><span class="filter active" data-filter=".all">Todos</span></li>
                                <?php
                                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
                                    {

                                        $termname = strtolower($term->name);  
                                        $termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);  

                                        echo '<li>
                                                <span class="filter" data-filter="' . '.' . $termname . '">
                                                    ' . $term->name . '
                                                </span>
                                              </li>';
                                    }

                                ?>
                            </ul>

                    <?php
                        
                        }

                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="row">

                    <?php 
                        $loop = new WP_Query(
                                        array(
                                            'post_type' => 'historias-de-exito', 
                                            'posts_per_page' => 3,
                                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                                            'order'   => 'DESC',
                                            'ignore_sticky_posts' => true                                            
                                        )
                                    );
                        $count = 0;
                    ?>

                    <div id="portfoliolist">

                        <?php 
                            
                            if ( $loop ) : 

                                while ( $loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

                                    $imagen__portada__exito = get_field( 'imagen__portada__exito' );
                                    $icono__casos__exito    = get_field( 'icono__casos__exito' );

                            ?>

                                    <?php
                                    $terms = get_the_terms( $loop->ID, 'historias-de-exitos' );

                                    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) : 
                                        $links = array();

                                        foreach ( $terms as $term ) 
                                        {
                                            $links[] = $term->name;
                                        }
                                        $links = str_replace(' ', '-', $links); 
                                        $tax = join( " ", $links ); 

                                        $link_category = get_term_link( strtolower($tax), 'historias-de-exitos' );

                                    else :  
                                        $tax = '';  
                                    endif;

                        ?>

                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">

                            <div class="content__portafolio <?php echo strtolower($tax); ?> all" data-cat="<?php echo strtolower($tax); ?>">
                                <img src="<?php echo $imagen__portada__exito; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                                <div class="content">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <h2><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
                                            <div class="sumilla">
                                                <?php echo the_excerpt(); ?>
                                            </div>
                                            <!-- -->

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- -->

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($loop->ID); ?>" class="btn__vermas">saber más</a>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-12">
                                            <div class="logo__reiva">
                                                <img src="<?php echo $icono__casos__exito; ?>" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                                            </div>

                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                    <!-- -->

                                </div>
                                <!-- -->

                            </div>
                            <!-- -->

                        </div>
                        <!-- -->

                        <?php 

                                endwhile; 
                            endif;
                        ?>

                    </div>
                    <!-- -->

                    <div id="boton">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="loadMore" class="btn__sabermas" page="1">Cargar más</a>

                    </div>
                    <!-- -->

                    
                </div>
                <!-- -->

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</section>

<div id="scrollUp">
  <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img/arrow-scroll.png" alt="">
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: can you check whether there are any console errors, i suspect this is a javascript issue.

Comment: It's a client-side issue, so php has no use here, we need to see JS

Answer (score 0):

You should try using Ajax to post and receive data. For an example of this check out: [jQuery Ajax Post with data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894744/jquery-ajax-post-with-data)